# Executing Elastic beanstalk environment with node.js but the it is not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have chosen to create an environment where to place in run Node.js with Elastic Beanstalk. I have installed properly mongodb into the amazon linux but I have not any node.js installed in the system even if I have choosen node.js as application environment. Do you have any idea? Should I have install node.js and npm manually into the instance?

Comment: if you are using a ubuntu instance, node might be installed at `nodejs` instead of `node`

Comment: Can you please explain, how you found that node.js and npm is not available on the EC2 instance? They are installed in specific directories and may not be available on your $PATH.

Comment: I execute node command from the terminal but I get command not found. I should check if it is somewhere in the file system

Comment: Yes beanstalk keeps these in its own directories. Can you please elaborate on your usecase? How would you like to use the node command?